# How can I find the index of row in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one html table which consists of a button on each row. When I click on that button I want to get the index of the row. With my code I am getting the index value but it starts with 1 instead of 0. In other examples I saw that row index is starting from value "0", but in my case it starts with "1". Can anybody help me where I did mistake.

Here is my table.

```
<div class="table-style table-municipality table-edit-community-view">
    <table id="sum_table">
        <tr class="titlerow">
            <th>S.N.</th>
            <th>Community</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Area</th>
            <th>Estimated</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <? 
        $sn = 1;
        while($result= mysql_fetch_row($res))
        {
            ?>
            <tr id="<?php echo $result[0];?>">
                <td align="center"><? echo $sn++; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><? echo $result[1] ?></td>
                <td align="center"><? echo $result[2] ?></td>
                <td align="center" class="rowDataSd"><? echo $result[3] ?></td>
                <td align="center" class="rowDataSd"><? echo $result[4] ?></td>
                <td align="center" class="rowDataSd"><? echo $result[5] ?></td>
                <td>
                    <button class="test">Test</button>
                </td>                       
            </tr>
            <?
        }
         ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

script:

```
$(".test").click(function(){
    console.log("name: ", $(this).closest('td').parent()[0].sectionRowIndex);
});
```

Comment: yes I have tried with tr as well but I get same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting index starting by 1 because you have one tr element in start of table for headers. You can -1 from returned index to get index starting with 0.

```
$(".test").click(function(){
  console.log("name: ", $(this).closest('tr').index()-1);
});
```

Or find the current rows index in collection of desired rows excluding headers row:

```
$(".test").click(function(){
  console.log("name: ", $('#sum_table tr:not(.titlerow)').index($(this).closest('tr')));
});
```

Comment: I was doing the -1 for temporary solution. Your second method helped me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function tells you that.

```
$(".test").click(function(){
    console.log("name: ", $(this).closest('td').parent().index());
});
```

Also note that you can probably just use `.closest('tr')` rather than `.closest('td').parent()`.

```
$(".test").click(function(){
    console.log("name: ", $(this).closest('tr').index());
});
```

**Note**, though, that your title row is in the same parent as your data rows, and so will occup the `index = 0` position. If you want to avoid that, put it in its own `thead` with the data rows in a `tbody`:

```
<div class="table-style table-municipality table-edit-community-view">
    <table id="sum_table">
        <thead><!-- *** Note -->
            <tr class="titlerow">
                <th>S.N.</th>
                <th>Community</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Area</th>
                <th>Estimated</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead><!-- *** Note -->
        <tbody><!-- *** Note -->
            <? 
            $sn = 1;
            while($result= mysql_fetch_row($res))
            {
                ?>
                <tr id="<?php echo $result[0];?>">
                    <td align="center"><? echo $sn++; ?></td>
                    <td align="center"><? echo $result[1] ?></td>
                    <td align="center"><? echo $result[2] ?></td>
                    <td align="center" class="rowDataSd"><? echo $result[3] ?></td>
                    <td align="center" class="rowDataSd"><? echo $result[4] ?></td>
                    <td align="center" class="rowDataSd"><? echo $result[5] ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="test">Test</button>
                    </td>                       
                </tr>
                <?
            }
             ?>
        </tbody><!-- *** Note -->
    </table>
</div>
```

It's generally best practice to use `thead` and `tbody` anyway.

Comment: I want result of index starting 0. Your solution and my solution are both giving me result from 1

Comment: @nas: No, it's giving the index starting with 0. If you want to exclude the title row, either subtract one from it or put that in a `thead`. (I've updated the answer to show how.)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".test").click(function() {
  console.log("name: ", $(this).closest('tbody tr').index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-style table-municipality table-edit-community-view">
  <table id="sum_table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="titlerow">
      <th>S.N.</th>
      <th>Community</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Area</th>
      <th>Estimated</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">1</td>
      <td align="center">1</td>
      <td align="center">1</td>
      <td align="center" class="rowDataSd">1</td>
      <td align="center" class="rowDataSd">1</td>
      <td align="center" class="rowDataSd">1</td>
      <td>
        <button class="test">Test</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">2</td>
      <td align="center">2</td>
      <td align="center">2</td>
      <td align="center" class="rowDataSd">2</td>
      <td align="center" class="rowDataSd">2</td>
      <td align="center" class="rowDataSd">2</td>
      <td>
        <button class="test">Test</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Use `tr` with `index()`

Comment: In your case result is 1 and 2. I want 0 and 1

Comment: @nas because the header row is 0.. you can group it anway. just add thead or tbody